# How to display facebook/linkedIn newsfeed/updates in blog

Tags: blogs

I have created a blog and i want to display facebook updates in the blog. i havn't found any site which helps this .can you help me to do this out.

Comment: Go read the first question in the FAQs : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: which blog system are you using?